# In Objective-C what utility uses @brief tag in comments?

Tags: objective-c, doxygen

I just started programming in Objective-C and found some example comments like the following:

```
/*!
@brief The UIImageView we use to display the image generated from the imageBuffer
*/
```

What is the purpose of `@brief`? Is this something related to a documentation system like Doxygen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. That is the **standard format** for a function description in doxygen, using the command `@brief` for a brief explanation.

Maybe you are more familiar with the expression `\brief`, but `@brief` is allowed too.
You have all the variations explained in [this section](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) of the manual.

Putting the command `@brief` will generate a short description of the function when you generate the doxygen documentation. That short description can be extended if you want.

Comment: I just learned that \short is a synonymous... http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/commands.html#cmdbrief

Answer (score 5):

Also this tag enable you to display your comments in Quick Help in Xcode.

[image]

Almost full pattern is:

```
/**
 @brief Example usage:
 @code
 @endcode
 @param param
 */
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a doxygen tag indeed.