# In an Angular 6 project, what does @brief mean?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a new Angular 6 project and I noticed that there are some few hashed comments that seems like this:

```
/** @brief the displayed list of vehicles */
```

and this:

```
/** @brief dummy database of vehicles */
```

and this '@brief' thing has a blue color, so what is this '@brief' mean?

Comment: maybe this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797377/in-objective-c-what-utility-uses-brief-tag-in-comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@brief Would help in documentation . Whatever code you write using  @brief will be used to generate a document .You can use any tool for document generation .

Answer (score 1):

This is **[JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/)** documentation syntax in JavaScript comment blocks.

However, the `@brief` tag is not a standard tag and seems to be borrowed from **doxygen**.

The closest JSDoc tag would be the [`@summary` tag](https://jsdoc.app/tags-summary.html) meaning "a shorter version of the full description".